# How does Vim "take control" of the terminal and allow it to be used as a modifiable buffer?

Tags: c++, linux, vim, terminal

How does Vim "take control" of the terminal and allow it to be used as a modifiable buffer?

How difficult would it be to create my own program which could arbitrarily modify the character buffer used by the terminal using a language like c++ (in linux)?

Comment: You can try ncurses: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: Vim does in fact use the `ncurses` library to provide the terminal manipulations. The modifiable buffer itself is just the terminal representation of what is contained in a number of varying data structures in memory that keeps track of the original, new and modified text since the last save (and a number of undo steps since the editing session began). There is no one simple modifiable buffer (except what is first loaded from, or saved to, disk). I don't know whether ncurses or the Vim source does that, but a few targets searches should disclose the approach.

Comment: Vim is free and open source software; look at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the output buffer is just a bunch of characters.

The most basic approach to use terminal as VIM does is to emit backspace.
The backspaces in terminal are non-destructive so they just move the cursor to the left.

So you can emit backspace till you find yourself in the right place.

If your terminal support ANSI escape sequences (the special text sequences) you can use `\033[number;numberH` to jump around e.g. `\033[3;3H` will jump to row 3 and height 3 then you can print something.

In **C** that is:

```
int row = 3;
int col = 3;

printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, col);
printf("Hello world");
```

Of course not all terminals support ANSI escape sequences.

That's why you've got [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library and the `move(row,col)` function.

You can also try to execute native functions.
I don't know what sits inside linux headers but in Windows the `winapi.h` provides efficient way to use the buffer: [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)